# JQuery slideToggle - changing text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to change some of my text whenever slideToggle is activated.

So for example, I have a text which when clicked some info is shown. The angle which is shown next to the text should then change from a down angle to an up angle.

I've tried it with the following code, but it just stays a down angle when it the slideToggle is activated again.

JQuery:

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        $('.fa-angle-down').remove();
        $header.prepend('<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
<h2>Title</h2>
<br>
<div class='header'><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-1x"></i> Title text</div>
<div class="content">
Content text
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}

.header {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML also

Comment: Added to the post @RinoRaj

Comment: Please could you add your CSS too?

Comment: Added it to the post @Ash

Comment: Don't see how it could possibly stay down when you remove all of the down icons in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the class within the slide complete callback

```
$header.find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) might suit your requirements better:

```
$(".header").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () { 
        $('.fa').toggleClass("angle-down");
    });

});
```

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u4v7p36u/2/).